# dropwizard test integration give an exception ConfigurationParsingException

Tags: java, mongodb, jetty, yaml, dropwizard

I 'm currently doing an integration test with the framwork dropwizard , embeddedmongo . but when I execute the tests , I always this exception .

```
com.example.pointypatient.integration.PointyPatientApplicationTest  Time elapsed: 3.054 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException: dropwizard-angular- example-master\target\test-classes\integration.yml has an error:Configuration at dropwizard-angular-example-master\target\test-classes\integration.yml must not be empty
```

and my integration.yml is here:

```
dbConfig:
  host: localhost
  port: 12345
  dbName: test

server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8080
    - type: https
      port: 8443
      keyStorePath: example.keystore
      keyStorePassword: example
      validateCerts: false
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8081
    - type: https
      port: 8444
      keyStorePath: example.keystore
      keyStorePassword: example
      validateCerts: false

# Logging settings.
logging:
  # The default level of all loggers. Can be OFF, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.
  level: INFO

  appenders:
    - type: console
```

thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

From [ConfigurationFactory.java](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/e441709c26800c3aaa41e0e5af308924ede2c1d5/dropwizard-configuration/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/configuration/ConfigurationFactory.java#L87), this exception is thrown only if the method `readTree` from `ObjectMapper` returns null.

- Look at `ConfigurationSourceProvider` derived class that you are passing to `build` method, as it is not handling `IOException` properly ( I can assume you are using a mocked one);
- Look at `path` argument, it seems you should be passing *"dropwizard-angular- example-master\target\test-classes\integration.yml"* instead of *"dropwizard-angular-example-master\target\test-classes\integration.yml"* *first path has an empty space just after **dropwizard-angular-**

Answer (score 1):

If your dropwizard-config file (i.e. `integration.yml`) is in `test/resources` directory, you don't need to use `ResourceHelpers.resourceFilePath("integration.yml")` to pass full config path into `DropwizardAppExtension` as a param, you should only pass its name (e.g. "integration.yml")

```
private static DropwizardAppExtension<MyDropwizardConfiguration> RULE = new DropwizardAppExtension<>(
            MyDropwizardApplication.class, "integration.yml");
```